# StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MainComponent -> MatDialog]

Tags: angular, angular-material

When using Materials Dialog, I can't remove the error mentioned in the subject. I had already imported the MatDialogModule and added the entryComponents. I simply want to open my edit-api component when the editAPI button is clicked inside my main component. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/exercise-basic-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change following

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
```

by

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

to resolve your error.

Comment: Oh thanks. I forgot that the new version of Angular requires us to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try following in your edit api component

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-alert-dialog',
  templateUrl: './alert-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class AlertDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<your_component>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data) { }

  closeDialog(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

You need to use @Inject MAT_DIALOG_DATA in your dialog component.